# insert/append value to pandas column at specific location without replacing existing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want conditional add to "remark" column without overwriting it.
I have following dataframe.

```
remark    Rule1    Rule2

Banana    False    False
Apple     True     False
Orange    False    True
Kiwi      True     True
```

if Rule1 == True then Red; if Rule2 == True then Yellow

I have written below code but it is overwriting existing value.

```
data.loc[data['Rule1']==True,"remark"] = "Red"
data.loc[data['Rule2']==True,"remark"] = "Yellow"
```

The expected output should be something like this:

```
remark            Rule1    Rule2

Banana            False    False
Apple, Red        True     False
Orange,Yellow     False    True
Kiwi, Red, Yellow True     True
```

Comment: simplified my previous answer with `+=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reassigning the values because you are setting the values of remark directly to Red or Yellow based on the condition instead of concatenating. You can do that by just modifying your code by using `+=` as -

```
data.loc[data['Rule1']==True,"remark"] += ', Red'
data.loc[data['Rule2']==True,"remark"] += ', Yellow'
```

```
              remark  Rule1  Rule2
0             Banana  False  False
1         Apple, Red   True  False
2     Orange, Yellow  False   True
3  Kiwi, Red, Yellow   True   True
```

(make sure you `data.reset_index()` incase remarks column is in the index)

PS. BEN_YO's approach is the interesting one you should spend time on.

---

If you have nans as you mentioned in the comments then you can do the following to avoid them completely.

```
data.loc[(data['Rule1']==True) & (data['remark'].notna()),"remark"] += ', Red'
data.loc[(data['Rule2']==True) & (data['remark'].notna()),"remark"] += ', Yellow'
```

Comment: Akshay, this is simple and crisp answer thank you so much! 
just a real quick query, it is fine if you don't want to answer since it is not in the question.
What if remark has some np.nan how will you handle that? because it is skipping the value for np.Nan
Appreciate your help man :)

Comment: So if there is a Nan, would you still want to append Red and Yellow to it?

Comment: Yes, even though it is np.nan it should append the value based on the rule. I did replace np.nan with None but then ', ' is appearing in the beginning

Comment: hmm, I am able to avoid them but I have to figure out how to still have the Red and Yellow without a comma at the start.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `dot`

```
df.remark = df.remark + ',' + df[['Rule1','Rule2']].dot(pd.Index(['Red,','Yellow,']))
df.remark = df.remark.str[:-1]
df
Out[88]: 
            remark  Rule1  Rule2
0           Banana  False  False
1        Apple,Red   True  False
2    Orange,Yellow  False   True
3  Kiwi,Red,Yellow   True   True
```